# Quasi-shuffle identity

Tags: calculus, integration, summation

I tried to evaluate the following sum:

> $$S=\left( \sum _{ { m }_{ 1 }=1 }^{ n }{ \frac { 1 }{ { m }_{ 1 } }  }  \right) \left( \sum _{ { m }_{ 2 }=1 }^{ n }{ \frac { 1 }{ { m }_{ 2 } }  }  \right) \left( \sum _{ { m }_{ 3 }=1 }^{ n }{ \frac { 1 }{ { m }_{ 3 } }  }  \right) $$

Now, since harmonic numbers satisfy quasi-shuffle identity, I tried to use it as follows:

> $$S=\left( \sum _{ n\ge { m }_{ 1 }>{ m }_{ 2 }>{ m }_{ 3 }>1 }^{  }{ + } \sum _{ n\ge { m }_{ 1 }>{ m }_{ 3 }>{ m }_{ 2 }>1 }^{  }{ + } \sum _{ n\ge { m }_{ 2 }>{ m }_{ 3 }>{ m }_{ 1 }>1 }^{  }{ + } \sum _{ n\ge { m }_{ 2 }>{ m }_{ 1 }>{ m }_{ 3 }>1 }^{  }{ + } \sum _{ n\ge { m }_{ 3 }>{ m }_{ 2 }>{ m }_{ 1 }>1 }^{  }{ + } \sum _{ n\ge { m }_{ 3 }>{ m }_{ 1 }>{ m }_{ 2 }>1 }^{  }{ + } \sum _{ n\ge { m }_{ 1 }>{ m }_{ 3 }={ m }_{ 2 }>1 }^{  }{ + } \sum _{ n\ge { m }_{ 2 }>{ m }_{ 3 }={ m }_{ 1 }>1 }^{  }{ + } \sum _{ n\ge { m }_{ 3 }>{ m }_{ 1 }={ m }_{ 2 }>1 }^{  }{ + } \sum _{ n\ge { m }_{ 1 }={ m }_{ 3 }>{ m }_{ 2 }>1 }^{  }{ + } \sum _{ n\ge { m }_{ 2 }={ m }_{ 3 }>{ m }_{ 2 }>1 }^{  }{ + } \sum _{ n\ge { m }_{ 1 }={ m }_{ 2 }>{ m }_{ 3 }>1 }^{  }{ + } \sum _{ n\ge { m }_{ 1 }={ m }_{ 2 }={ m }_{ 3 }>1 }^{  }{  }  \right) \frac { 1 }{ { m }_{ 1 }{ m }_{ 2 }{ m }_{ 3 } }$$

This comes out to be

> $$S={ 6H }_{ n }\left( 1,1,1 \right) +{ 3H }_{ n }\left( 2,1 \right) +{ 3H }_{ n }\left( 1,2 \right) +{ H }_{ n }\left( 3 \right)$$

So my question is have I done it correctly. If I've done any mistake please correct me.

Comment: Aren't the three factors in the original expression equal to each other?

Comment: Yes @AdityaAgarwal. All the tree factors are equal.

Comment: Yes, I figured that out when I saw the note by Ishan Singh :).

Comment: Yes @AdityaAgarwal. Did you see my solution?

Comment: Yup, but I don't really know what is Quasi-shuffle identity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's OK.

One may rewrite the relation you give as

> $$
> H_{n}^{3}(1) = 6H_{n}(1, 1, 1) + 3H_{n}(2, 1) + 3H_{n}(1, 2) + H_{n}(3) \tag1
> $$

where
$$
H_{n}(s_{1}, \cdots, s_{l}) = \sum_{n \geq k_{1} > k_{2} > \dots > k_{l} > 0 }\frac{1}{k_{1}^{s_{1}} \cdots k_{l}^{s_{l}}}. \tag2
$$
Another way to see $(1)$ is

> $$
> \left(\sum_{m=1}^n{\frac1m}\right)^3=6\sum_{m=1}^n{\frac1{m}}\sum_{k=1}^{m-1}{\frac{H_{k-1}}k}+3\sum_{m=1}^n{\frac{H_{m-1}}{m^2}}+3\sum_{m=1}^n{\frac1{m}\sum_{k=1}^{m-1}{\frac1{k^2}}}+\sum_{m=1}^n{\frac1{m^3}} \tag3
> $$

where $\displaystyle H_n:=\sum_{m=1}^n\frac1m$ is the standard harmonic number.

Many thanks are due to [Leonhard Euler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leonhard_Euler).

Comment: Thanks a lot for confirming it :)